# Create or Open file then write data at a specific position

Tags: node.js

I have a filename, an offset into the file, and a byte of data and I need to write a function to store the byte of data at the offset in the file. It needs to create the file if it does not exist but open the existing one if not. It needs to add the data at the specified location in the file, extending it if necessary.

However none of the options to fs.openFile seem to work. They either fail if the file doesn't exist, truncate the file if it already exists, or do not allow "seek" to write data at a position in the file using the offset in a write.

How can I achieve what I need?
This is using nodejs on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has access rights to every file. The won't open if not given rights. Especially for writing purpose.
Make sure you first create one, give Read/Write access to the file and then try. I had similar issue with PHP on Fedora Server.

Comment: I have rights, that's not the problem.
The issue is that you have to give the open or openSync an open flags like "rw" or "r+" or "a" and none of them seem to give the behavour I need. They either fail if the file doesn't exist, or truncate an existing file, or do not allow "seeking" on linux.